# Help understanding proof of Legendre's formula

Tags: number-theory

Can somebody kindly help me in understanding below highlighted line in [proof of Legendre's formula](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Legendre's_Formula)

Particularly this step :
$$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{x}e_j(p^{j-1}+p^{j-2}+\ldots+1) $$

How are the both sides same ? In that link the proof is short and they are not explaining in a clear/easy way.

[image]

Comment: The result is obtained by taking the closed form of a finite geometric sum:$$\sum_{j=1}^{x}e_j(p^{j-1}+p^{j-2}+\ldots+1)=\sum_{j=1}^{x}e_j\left(\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}p^k\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{x}e_j\frac{1-p^{j-1+1}}{1-p}$$

Comment: Oh I see that thank you :) but my real big problem is with left side of equality. How does  the infinite sum from part 1 turn into the left side of this equality is what i am not getting

Comment: this step :  $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{x}e_j(p^{j-1}+p^{j-2}+\ldots+1)$$ How are they both same ?

Comment: It's almost impossible to read that text. Can you type out what exactly your problem is, and put that into the body of the question (using proper formatting)?

Comment: really sorry Gerry, here is the complete proof http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Legendre%27s_Formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ suppose m=p^{j-1}+p^{j-2}+p^{j-3}+...+p^2+p^1+1 \\multiply \\m\\ by\\ p\\ mp=p^{j}+p^{j-1}+p^{j-2}+...+p^3+p^2+p\\
now\\mp-m=?\\mp-m=p^{j}+p^{j-1}+p^{j-2}+...+p^3+p^2+p -(p^{j-1}+p^{j-2}+p^{j-3}+...+p^2+p^1+1)\\mp-m=p^j-1\\m(p-1)=p^j-1\\m=\frac{p^j-1}{p-1} \\or\\m=m=\frac{1-p^j}{1-p} \\$$

Comment: Yes I got that part thanks ! Left side of equality is still a mystery to me. Kindly read the updated question, sorry for the edit.